# AS3 protected method are inaccessible for subclass in mxml

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

for a parent class A contains a protected method f() :

```
public class A {

protected  function f():void
        {
        }
}

public class B extends A{
}
```

when i create an mxml and create an instance of B with imports all of A and B (are in the same package)

```
B b = new B();
//the problem :
b.f(); // inaccessible method !!
```

Comment: What is the point of downvoting this question? He described his problem clearly, provided code examples and the expected result is implied. If you're downvoting a question because the user has little experience in coding, we might as well shut the whole site down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. You need to read more about OOP.

What you are missing here is that trying to call f() on an instance of A would have the same effect. By definition only public methods are callable. Protected methods are only available for call and override inside the implementation of subclasses and super classes, they are not public and so they are not callable on instances outside the scope of subclasses. Protected are very much like private methods except that they are available for call and override within the scope of subclasses.